# Signal Analysis/Processing Textbook

Tags: reference-request, signal-analysis, textbook-recommendation

Can anybody recommend me a decent Signal Analysis/Processing textbook. If possible one that deals a little with MATLAB. I have an little knowledge of Real Analysis and fourier transforms. Wavelets i have only had a brief introduction to.

Thanks

Edit: Sorry for the vague state of the question, I was hoping for a text that would give a decent background to time-Frequency linear methods including; FFT, windowed FFT, Filtering & wavelets. Also an introduction to non linear signals and the related methods.

Some methods of particular interest are the smooth windowed Wigner-Ville,Goertzel's algorithm and Prony's.

Comment: There is not enough information -- what exactly do you need this for? There are literally hundreds of equally valid answers otherwise.

Comment: Contemporary Communication Systems Using MATLAB 
John G. Proakis , Masoud Salehi , Gerhard Bauch 
http://www.amazon.com/Contemporary-Communication-Systems-Using-MATLAB/dp/0534406173


Comment: You may also ask at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ but I agree with Igor that it is not really clear what you want 

Comment: I guess we can close this as no longer relevant then.

Comment: See also answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112303/signal-processing-reference-for-pure-mathematician

Answer (score 1):

Try this one http://www.editions-ellipses.fr/product_info.php?products_id=646 
by Alain Yger, but it's in french. On his website http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~ayger/pluri.html you will find matlab routines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your research about, but I think this book can help you

Kay, S. M. (1993). Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing. Upper Side River, New Jersey: Prentice Hall PTR

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this book will be helpful: [http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Signal-Processing-Practical-Approach/dp/0201596199](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201596199) (Digital Signal Processing: A Practical Approach, by  E. Ifeachor and B. Jervis).